# Writing a script to run multiple scripts in Python

Tags: python, function, shell, boot

I’m building an alarm clock project. Can anyone tell me how to write a script to call on all of the other scripts. For example, I have three scripts on my raspberry pi called LCDTESTFORPI.py, another called “ex_7segmentLED.py” and a third called “alarmpi.py”. What I would like is to be able to run a script called “alarmpi_init.py” which would run all of the other scripts, and could then be set to run on startup. I know it is possible I just don’t know how to write it.

Previously, it has been suggested that rather than this I should use the correct format, by putting all of these into functions of one script, but I don’t know how to do this.

Below is a copy of the codes mentioned:

LCDTESTFORPI.py

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
#
# HD44780 20x4 RGB LCD Test Script for
# Raspberry Pi
# 
# Adapted by: Kyle Prier
# Site: http://wwww.youtube.com/meistervision
# 
# Original Author : Matt Hawkins
# Site   : http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/
# 
# Date   : 09/08/2012
#

# The wiring for the LCD is as follows:
# 1 : GND
# 2 : 5V
# 3 : Contrast (0-5V)*
# 4 : RS (Register Select)
# 5 : R/W (Read Write)       - GROUND THIS PIN! We do not want the LCD to send anything to the Pi @ 5v
# 6 : Enable or Strobe
# 7 : Data Bit 0             - NOT USED
# 8 : Data Bit 1             - NOT USED
# 9 : Data Bit 2             - NOT USED
# 10: Data Bit 3             - NOT USED
# 11: Data Bit 4
# 12: Data Bit 5
# 13: Data Bit 6
# 14: Data Bit 7
# 15: LCD Backlight +5V
# 16: LCD Backlight GND (Red)
# 17: LCD Backlight GND (Green)
# 18: LCD Backlight GND (Blue)

#import
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

# Define GPIO to LCD mapping
LCD_RS = 25
LCD_E  = 24
LCD_D4 = 23
LCD_D5 = 17
LCD_D6 = 27
LCD_D7 = 22


# Define some device constants
LCD_WIDTH = 20    # Maximum characters per line
LCD_CHR = True
LCD_CMD = False

LCD_LINE_1 = 0x80 # LCD RAM address for the 1st line
LCD_LINE_2 = 0xC0 # LCD RAM address for the 2nd line
LCD_LINE_3 = 0x94 # LCD RAM address for the 3rd line
LCD_LINE_4 = 0xD4 # LCD RAM address for the 4th line 

# Timing constants
E_PULSE = 0.0005
E_DELAY = 0.0005

daynames = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
monthnames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]

def ordinal(value):
    try:
        value = int(value)
    except ValueError:
        return value

    if value % 100//10 != 1:
        remainder = value % 10
        if remainder == 1:
            ordval = u"%d%s" % (value, "st")
        elif remainder == 2:
            ordval = u"%d%s" % (value, "nd")
        elif remainder  == 3:
            ordval = u"%s%s" % (value, "rd")
        else:
            ordval = u"%d%s" % (value, "th")
    else:
        ordval = u"%d%s" % (value, "th")
    return ordval

def main():
  # Main program block
  GPIO.setwarnings(False)
  GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)       # Use BCM GPIO numbers
  GPIO.setup(LCD_E, GPIO.OUT)  # E
  GPIO.setup(LCD_RS, GPIO.OUT) # RS
  GPIO.setup(LCD_D4, GPIO.OUT) # DB4
  GPIO.setup(LCD_D5, GPIO.OUT) # DB5
  GPIO.setup(LCD_D6, GPIO.OUT) # DB6
  GPIO.setup(LCD_D7, GPIO.OUT) # DB7

  # Initialise display
  lcd_init()


  # Send some centred test
  lcd_byte(LCD_LINE_1, LCD_CMD)
  lcd_string("--------------------",2) 
  lcd_byte(LCD_LINE_2, LCD_CMD)
  lcd_string("AlarmPi Mk2",2)
  lcd_byte(LCD_LINE_3, LCD_CMD)
  lcd_string("Starting up...",2)
  lcd_byte(LCD_LINE_4, LCD_CMD)
  lcd_string("--------------------",2)    

  time.sleep(5) # 5 second delay 

  while True:
    lcd_byte(LCD_LINE_1, LCD_CMD)
    lcd_string("Wakey Wakey!",2)
    lcd_byte(LCD_LINE_2, LCD_CMD)
    lcd_string(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"),2)  
    lcd_byte(LCD_LINE_3, LCD_CMD)
    day_index = int(time.strftime("%w"))
    lcd_string(daynames[day_index],2) 
    lcd_byte(LCD_LINE_4, LCD_CMD)
    mon_index = int(time.strftime("%m"))
    lcd_string(ordinal(int(time.strftime("%d"))) + " " + monthnames[mon_index] + " " + time.strftime("%Y"),2)
    time.sleep(1)

  time.sleep(30) # 30 second delay 

  # Clear display
  lcd_byte(LCD_LINE_1, LCD_CMD)
  lcd_string("",3)
  lcd_byte(LCD_LINE_2, LCD_CMD)
  lcd_string("",3)  
  lcd_byte(LCD_LINE_3, LCD_CMD)
  lcd_string("",2) 
  lcd_byte(LCD_LINE_4, LCD_CMD)
  lcd_string("",2)    

  time.sleep(3) # 3 second delay  


def lcd_init():
  # Initialise display
  lcd_byte(0x33,LCD_CMD)
  lcd_byte(0x32,LCD_CMD)
  lcd_byte(0x28,LCD_CMD)
  lcd_byte(0x0C,LCD_CMD)  
  lcd_byte(0x06,LCD_CMD)
  lcd_byte(0x01,LCD_CMD)  

def lcd_string(message,style):
  # Send string to display
  # style=1 Left justified
  # style=2 Centred
  # style=3 Right justified

  if style==1:
    message = message.ljust(LCD_WIDTH," ")  
  elif style==2:
    message = message.center(LCD_WIDTH," ")
  elif style==3:
    message = message.rjust(LCD_WIDTH," ")

  for i in range(LCD_WIDTH):
    lcd_byte(ord(message[i]),LCD_CHR)

def lcd_byte(bits, mode):
  # Send byte to data pins
  # bits = data
  # mode = True  for character
  #        False for command

  GPIO.output(LCD_RS, mode) # RS

  # High bits
  GPIO.output(LCD_D4, False)
  GPIO.output(LCD_D5, False)
  GPIO.output(LCD_D6, False)
  GPIO.output(LCD_D7, False)
  if bits&0x10==0x10:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D4, True)
  if bits&0x20==0x20:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D5, True)
  if bits&0x40==0x40:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D6, True)
  if bits&0x80==0x80:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D7, True)

  # Toggle 'Enable' pin
  time.sleep(E_DELAY)    
  GPIO.output(LCD_E, True)  
  time.sleep(E_PULSE)
  GPIO.output(LCD_E, False)  
  time.sleep(E_DELAY)      

  # Low bits
  GPIO.output(LCD_D4, False)
  GPIO.output(LCD_D5, False)
  GPIO.output(LCD_D6, False)
  GPIO.output(LCD_D7, False)
  if bits&0x01==0x01:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D4, True)
  if bits&0x02==0x02:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D5, True)
  if bits&0x04==0x04:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D6, True)
  if bits&0x08==0x08:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D7, True)

  # Toggle 'Enable' pin
  time.sleep(E_DELAY)    
  GPIO.output(LCD_E, True)  
  time.sleep(E_PULSE)
  GPIO.output(LCD_E, False)  
  time.sleep(E_DELAY)   

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Here is a copy of the ex_7segmentclock.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import datetime

from Adafruit_LED_Backpack import SevenSegment

# ===========================================================================
# Clock Example
# ===========================================================================
segment = SevenSegment.SevenSegment(address=0x70)

# Initialize the display. Must be called once before using the display.
segment.begin()

print "Press CTRL+Z to exit"

# Continually update the time on a 4 char, 7-segment display
while(True):
  now = datetime.datetime.now()
  hour = now.hour
  minute = now.minute
  second = now.second

  segment.clear()
  # Set hours
  segment.set_digit(0, int(hour / 10))     # Tens
  segment.set_digit(1, hour % 10)          # Ones
  # Set minutes
  segment.set_digit(2, int(minute / 10))   # Tens
  segment.set_digit(3, minute % 10)        # Ones
  # Toggle colon
  segment.set_colon(second % 2)              # Toggle colon at 1Hz

  # Write the display buffer to the hardware.  This must be called to
  # update the actual display LEDs.
  segment.write_display()

  # Wait a quarter second (less than 1 second to prevent colon blinking getting$
  time.sleep(0.25)
```

Unfortunately I cannot get the other two code files to open as one is a .config file and the other is currently running from a device in a different part of the country. But the two code files shown are the two I would like to work with for this post.

Comment: @downvoters : Will Marks has finally posted his message here after being strongly suggested so from the Raspberry Pi SE. So please refrain from sanctioning again and help!

Comment: @Nasha Thank you Nasha very kind - sorry for the previous!

Answer (score 0):

If all the files reside in the same directory, this could be a possible implementation of `alarmpi_init.py`:

```
import LCDTESTFORPI
LCDTESTFORPI.main()

import ex_7segmentLED
import alarmpi
```

This will execute all the three scripts in that order.
Notice that scripts with `if __name__ == '__main__'` require an explicit invocation of their main method, whereas scripts without this section will work without it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like creating a file called `alarm_init.sh` with:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /my/working/directory/
./script1.py  # you can add arguments space separated.
./script2.py
./script3.py
```